# Kafka-Streams: How to query RocksDB persistent store when the key is avro serialized?

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I am building a kafka streams topology in which I need to materialize the contents of a Global KTable in a persistent RocksDB store. This store will be further used on every instance of my application for querying.

The store consinsts of key values pairs, where the key is serialized using Avro and the payload is just a byte array.

> My problem is when I try to query the store by a specific key, as shown in the code below:

```
fun topology() {
        val streamsBuilder = StreamsBuilder()

        streamsBuilder.globalTable<Key, ByteArray>(
                SOURCE_TOPIC_FOR_GLOBAL_KTABLE,
                Consumed.with(null /*Uses default serde provided in config which is SpecificAvroSerde*/,
                        Serdes.ByteArray()),
                Materialized.`as`(STORE_NAME))

        val kafkaStreams = KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(), getProperties(), DefaultKafkaClientSupplier())

        kafkaStreams.start()
    }

    private fun getProperties(): Properties {
        val properties = Properties()

        properties[StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "kafka-brokers-ip"
        properties[AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG] = "schema-registry-ip"
        properties[StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG] = "app-id"
        properties[ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG] = "client-id"
        properties[ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG] = "earliest"
        properties[StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG] = "C:/dev/kafka-streams"

        properties[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG] = SpecificAvroSerde::class.java
        properties[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG] = SpecificAvroSerde::class.java

        return properties
    }
```

And this is the function that I use to query the store:

```
val store = kafkaStreams
                .store(STORE_NAME, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore<Key, ByteArray>())

        store.all().forEach { keyValue ->
            if (keyValue.key == Key("25-OCT-19 USD")) {
                //we get here, so the key is in the store
                println("Keys are equal.")
                println(keyValue) // this gets printed: KeyValue({"value": "25-OCT-19 USD"}, [B@3ca343b5)
                println(store.get(Key("25-OCT-19 USD"))) //this is null
                println(store.get(keyValue.key)) //this is also null
            }
        }
```

> As you can see in the comments of code, there are values in the store, but when I try to query by a specific key, I get nothing back.

Comment: How are you creating `Key` class? Is `==` doing value comparison or referential comparison? Because `store.get` might not use the same thing...

Comment: Key it's an Avro object. == is equals in Kotlin. I've tried both rocks db persistent store and a LRUMap. Same problem. What I noticed is that the keys are stored as byte arrays in the map. When I do a get on the store the key gets serialez into a byte array and the lookup is performed using the byte array

Comment: I have some code that uses Avro objects generated by avro-maven-plugin as the keys and it works fine, using similar code that you have here with `store.get`. So, again, how do you create the object?

Comment: What do you mean by how you create the object? The value is published to kafka by a connector. The Key object that I use to query is created using the avro generated constrcutor.

Comment: Strange is that while I iterate over the elements of the store and I do a `get` using the key of the keyvalue pair, I still get null back.

Comment: How did the "avro generated constructor" get *generated*? What tooling are you using to go from an Avro schema to a specific class? But yeah, that is strange

Comment: Avro gradle plugin. https://github.com/davidmc24/gradle-avro-plugin/blob/master/README.md

Comment: The comparison happens on `byte[]` level -- hence, you need to ensure that the serializers that you use to populate the state store the one used during lookup are the same. Maybe the issue is with the magic byte that Confluent's Avro Serializers are using?

Comment: So I finally managed to solve the issue by remapping the keys and values to a different topic. I'm not 100% sure but I think the problem is due to the fact that the schema, registered by the source connector, although compatible with the one used by the streaming application, is not exactly the same. What I belive happened is that keys were stored as byte arrays, serialized with the schema registered by the connector. My avro object was generated with a compatible schema, so the deserialization was working, but when serialized to its bytearray format, the values would no longer match.

Comment: Also, I see another issue regarding this. Take the following use case: I have a store with keys serialized with schema id 1. Given that I use the KafkaAvroSerializer, the serialized key will be prefixed with the schema id. If I want to evolve the schema, I'll get a new id, so the byte arrays will no longer match. What are my options here?